Should we use the 'Shove' tag?
Looking through the list of newly created tags there is a shove tag created for this question. that isn't used anywhere else. Should we keep this tag and tag all questions about shoving with it or is that a bad idea and the tag should be burninated?

"Should we keep this tag and tag all questions about shoving with it or is that a bad idea and the tag should be burninated?" burninating a tag doesn't mean the questions with said tag should be removed just because they have said tag. They are removed if the question itself merits removal, regardless of which tag(s) it had.

@VLAZ Of course we would not delete the question. I am not sure what gave you that impression.

The two presented choices in the quote were: 1. leave the tag and all the questions 2. Don't do that and burninate.

@VLAZ Ah, I see the misunderstanding now. The 1. option is meant to be "Keep the tag and apply it to all questions where it is appliclable" and the 2. is "delete the tag", the questions would be kept regardless of choice.

No, we don’t need it. I’ve removed it and added actions and attack. Most questions related to the shove attack in 5e will have those tags, but if you find any that don’t, feel free to add those two.

I added [tag:forced-movement] afterward, which seems like it would cover Shove topically.

@doppelgreener Wouldn't that mean we should make Shove a Synonym of that?

@TreeSpawned That's not really necessary until we start seeing a repeated problem that synonyms would solve, and this is the first time we've seen shove come up, but it's an option. For example forced-movement has covered several topics for ten years and does not currently have any synonyms.

And I’m not sure every shove question will necessarily be a forced movement question.

Example: "Can I use the Shove spell to start an avalanche?" would not be forced movement

burninate!
I do not see a reason to retain it.
